# How to change Document Root for Apache2 in Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx, apache-2.2

The default location of Document root as per  httpd.conf is `/Library/WebServer/Documents`. I want this location to be `/webcontent`. So to do that, I created a webcontent folder in root(/).
Then in the httpd.conf:

- Changed the Document root line to DocumentRoot `/webcontent`
- Changed the Directory tag to `<Directory "/webcontent">`;

After restarting the Apache I'm getting the following page:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Could anyone please tell me whether I need to change any permissions anywhere else to change the document root?

Comment: Do you have an `index.html` stored in `/webcontent/`?

Comment: No, but I have a test.html placed inside the webcontent folder. When I  access it I'm getting this forbidden error. Is it mandatory to add index.html?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `httpd.conf` file provided with OS X has a default deny that locks down every directory from every client.  It then allows access to the `DocumentRoot` directory — that would be the default of `/Library/WebServer/Documents`.  Page down some in that file and you'll see:

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    # [...]
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    # [...]
    AllowOverride None

    # [...]
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Change the `"/Library/WebServer/Documents"` bit to `"/webcontent"` and you're good.

Answer (score 1):

To follow on from @Bred Ackerman answer if your using apache vhost you will need to add: private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/fred/Sites"
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```